# flattern scala array data type column to multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Is their any possible way to flatten an array in Scala DF?

As I know with columns and select filed.a works, but I don't want to specify them Manually.

```
  df.printSchema()
 |-- client_version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- filed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
```

final df

```
df.printSchema()
     |-- client_version: string (nullable = true)
     |-- filed_a: string (nullable = true)
     |-- filed_b: string (nullable = true)
     |-- filed_c: string (nullable = true)
     |-- filed_d: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Using `df.select("filed.a")` will not produce your desired schema. It will produce column of Arrays, not individual String values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten your `ArrayType` column with `explode` and `map` the nested struct element names to the wanted top-level column names, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class S(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String)

val df = Seq(
  ("1.0", Seq(S("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"))),
  ("2.0", Seq(S("a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"), S("a3", "b3", "c3", "d3")))
).toDF("client_version", "filed")

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- client_version: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- filed: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)

val dfFlattened = df.withColumn("filed_element", explode($"filed"))

val structElements = dfFlattened.select($"filed_element.*").columns

val dfResult = dfFlattened.select( col("client_version") +: structElements.map( 
    c => col(s"filed_element.$c").as(s"filed_$c")
  ): _*
)

dfResult.show
// +--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |client_version|filed_a|filed_b|filed_c|filed_d|
// +--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |           1.0|     a1|     b1|     c1|     d1|
// |           2.0|     a2|     b2|     c2|     d2|
// |           2.0|     a3|     b3|     c3|     d3|
// +--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

dfResult.printSchema
// root
//  |-- client_version: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- filed_a: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- filed_b: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- filed_c: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- filed_d: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` to flatten the arrays by adding more rows and then `select` with the `*` notation to bring the `struct` columns back to the top.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, explode, struct}
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("1", "a", "a", "a"),
  ("1", "b", "b", "b"),
  ("2", "a", "a", "a"),
  ("2", "b", "b", "b"),
  ("2", "c", "c", "c"),
  ("3", "a", "a","a")).toDF("idx",  "A", "B", "C")
  .groupBy(("idx"))
  .agg(collect_list(struct("A", "B", "C")).as("nested_col"))

df.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- idx: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- nested_col: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- C: string (nullable = true)

df.show
// +---+--------------------+
// |idx|          nested_col|
// +---+--------------------+
// |  3|         [[a, a, a]]|
// |  1|[[a, a, a], [b, b...|
// |  2|[[a, a, a], [b, b...|
// +---+--------------------+

val dfExploded = df.withColumn("exploded", explode($"nested_col")).drop("nested_col")

dfExploded.show
// +---+---------+
// |idx| exploded|
// +---+---------+
// |  3|[a, a, a]|
// |  1|[a, a, a]|
// |  1|[b, b, b]|
// |  2|[a, a, a]|
// |  2|[b, b, b]|
// |  2|[c, c, c]|
// +---+---------+

val finalDF = dfExploded.select("idx", "exploded.*")

finalDF.show
// +---+---+---+---+
// |idx|  A|  B|  C|
// +---+---+---+---+
// |  3|  a|  a|  a|
// |  1|  a|  a|  a|
// |  1|  b|  b|  b|
// |  2|  a|  a|  a|
// |  2|  b|  b|  b|
// |  2|  c|  c|  c|
// +---+---+---+---+
```